# Property of a function given a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I found the following exercise in my calculus notes:

> Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ for all $a\in [0,1].$ Show that $f(q)=0$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ iff $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1].$

I have proven that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ implies $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1],$ but I haven't been able to prove the other direction. Any help is welcome

Comment: Every real number $a$ is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers $x$.  Now what does the condition tell you $f(a)$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exists $a\in [0,1]\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(a)\neq 0$. By hypothesis, we know $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)\neq0.$ But if we take a sequence of rationals $\{r_n\}$ with $r_n \to a$, clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(r_n)=0$, which is a contradiction.